# How is angle measured by telescope in spectrometer is twice the prism angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics

While measuring the angle of the prism with the help of telescope in a spectrometer (see figure below), the observed angle is twice the angle of the prism. Can someone prove it geometrically?

Edit : How is the angle w.r.t median (C) is equal to angle b/w surface and reflected ray?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your diagram as a reference, the rays from the source are parallel to the (vertical) median of the prism (C). The surface(s) they are incident on are inclined by angles $a$ and $a'$ to this median. So the incident ray makes an angle of $a$ and $a'$ with the respective surfaces (note: not with the normal). From the law of reflection (equality of angles of incidence and reflection), they are also reflected at angles of $a$ and $a'$to the surface, and therefore are deviated by an angle $2a$ and $2a'$ respectively from their original path. Now, since $A = a+a'$, the total deviation is $2A$.

Comment: This also works even if the incoming rays are not parallel to the median plane. Thus the notation a and a' in the graph.

Comment: Yes, true enough. The total deviation is $2(a+a') = 2A$. I went with what the picture directly seemed to depict.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: the main thing i am not getting is how are both angles equal to "a" (right side) and a′ (left side). i mean how is angle wrt median (C) is equal to angle b/w surface and reflected ray? (geometrical explanation would be better)

Comment: Alternate interior angles for two parallel lines cut by a transversal are equal. So the angle of incidence is $a$ (right side) or $a'$ (left side). The law of reflection makes the angle between the surface and reflected ray also equal to this.